# R programming with loops

Tags: r, loops

I have the following 3x3 square matrix `a` and a vector `x`:

```
a = matrix(c(1.0, 0.1, 0.5, 
             0.1, 1.0, 0.9,
             0.5, 0.9, 1.0), nrow=3, ncol=3)

x = c(0.1,0.2,0.3)
```

I would like to following formula basically using the upper triangle of the matrix and vector

```
y = (a12 - (x1/x2)^2 + (a13 - x1/x3)^2 + (a23 - x2/x3)^2
```

I used the following for loop in R for the above formula, I getting the following error:

```
Error in a[i, j] : subscript out of bounds
```

I would greatly appreciate if you could please let me know if I'm doing anything incorrectly.

```
## initialize y
y = 0 

for (i in 1 : nrow(a)-1){
  for (j in i+1 : nrow(a)){
    y = y + ((a[i,j]) - (x[i]/x[j])^2
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing some parenthesis, otherwise `n:m` will define some unanticipated sequence which to R looks like any other vector and can interact with the other math.

Original code, with formula replaced by printing indexes:

```
for (i in 1 : nrow(a)-1){
+   for (j in i+1 : nrow(a)){
+ print(c(i,j))
+ }
+ }
[1] 0 1
[1] 0 2
[1] 0 3
[1] 1 2
[1] 1 3
[1] 1 4
[1] 2 3
[1] 2 4
[1] 2 5
```

Those `0`s and `5`s arent in range.

But if put parenthesis everywhere, it behaves:

```
for (i in (1 : (nrow(a)-1))){
+   for (j in ((i+1) : nrow(a))){
+ print(c(i,j))
+ }
+ }
[1] 1 2
[1] 1 3
[1] 2 3
```

Answer (score 11):

You can avoid the loop using this:

```
b <- a - outer(x,x,`/`)
sum(b[upper.tri(b)]^2)
```

Result

```
[1] 0.2422222
```